# Memory leak with MVVM Silverlight page navigation

Tags: memory-leaks, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

We have a application which is making use of MVVM Light Toolkit (http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). The page has Telerik Silverlight controls (grid and chart).

When we navigate from one page to other the memory usage is increasing by 100 MB for each click. finally after lot of click it's crashing. The memory is released only when browser is closed. Do we need to implement ICleanup ?

Comment: ICleanup would probably not help in your case, it's a declarative thing, not an automated process.

Comment: How do you create your ViewModels and your Models? You probably have too much of one of them, ie thinking you're using the same VM when you're actually creating new instances.

Comment: you are right. I'm using the same ViewModel in 3 UserControl and using in a single page. Code: `[Import(typeof(IViewModel))] public ViewModelBase ViewModel get { return this.DataContext as ViewModelBase; } set { this.DataContext = value; } }` calling the above code in Constructor of View. Using RIA and have a layer for Model and ViewModel. What is the best way to use It?

Comment: You probably want to use some DataBinding in XAML, with either a single location (like App.xaml) or a Singleton, or an IoC container. The templates for MVVM Light provide a ViewModelLocator class that can either function as a Singleton provider or a wrapper for an IoC container.